# Why wasn't I warned for my flag abuse?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

I failed to grasp SE rules and have flagged countless of answers that were false in my opinion.

Given that this is against the site policy, why didn't I receive a warning from moderators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are lenient on flag abuse because we'd rather get more reports than less. It used to be possible at some point to be banned forever from flagging by having enough invalid flags in a row, but I... *believe* this is no longer a thing.